# Pass object to parent component AngularJS 1.5.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a bit confusing with passing object from child component to parent in Angular 1.5. I have this markup:

index template:

```
<p>
  <parent></parent>
</p>
```

Parent component has such:

```
<li ng-repeat="obj in $ctrl.objectList"></li>
<child></child>
```

Child creates new objects. So I want to update objectList when new object is created.

```
require: {
  pCtrl: '^parent'
}
```

does not work for me. I wanted to to call some ctrl.parent.updateList(obj) function from parent component to update list. But I get error, that 'parent' not found. So, I'm not really understand how to do it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: It's not working of course, but the idea has to be clear. https://plnkr.co/edit/tCHWGz3k9epHqpEX4ze4

Comment: I've checked you plunkr. You have few mistypes there and I'm not sure that it is good to create a separate module for each component... But it works. You are doing right, here is [the corrected plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Bf9Kx8G1gqs2t0WnUTIb?p=preview)

Comment: So, the thing was to put <child> on top of parent template. I had child inside some dives before. Doesn't make sense for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm not: https://plnkr.co/edit/Bf9Kx8G1gqs2t0WnUTIb?p=preview :)
You still have some mistype I hope :)

Comment: Yes. I had it inside of pagedlide. So, now it works. But I still need it to be inside of pageslide

Comment: Edit my fiddle to be like you want - and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Here you go [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/KkO4tNDCJVoQmWw2cFgi?p=info)

Comment: There are some errors in you pageslide.js with css classes (https://plnkr.co/edit/yo2laI9uQf6aJ3hhKCTH?p=info).
Use Firefox inspector.
A lot of delopers prefer to make some css classes and assign them from directive rather then write styles directly, to avoid potential errors and keep code clean.
I'm not quite sure what you want to do with pagestyle.js, but In some approaches they try to minimize dom manipulations from js, and achieving any result they want by switching templates and classes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll try to resolve my problem.